# Find the maximum value that the quantity $2m+7n$ can have

Tags: number-theory

> Find the maximum value that the quantity $2m+7n$ can have such that there exist distinct positive integers $x_i$ $(1 \leq i \leq m)$, $y_j$ $(1 \leq j \leq n)$ such that the $x_i$'s are even, the $y_j$'s are odd, and $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i+\sum_{j=1}^n y_j = 1986$.

We see that $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i \geq 2+4+\cdots+m = \dfrac{(m+2)\frac{m}{2}}{2} = \dfrac{(m+2)m}{4}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \geq n^2$. What do we do from here to maximize $2m+7n$?

Answer (score 1):

Your sum of the $x$'s is not correct.  You should have $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i \geq 2+4+\cdots+2m = \dfrac{(2m+2)m}{2} = m(m+1)$  You must have $n$ even-why?  You are maximizing $2m+7n$ subject to $m(m+1)+n^2 \le 1986$.  Clearly we must have $n \le \lfloor \sqrt 1986 \rfloor=44$  The simple approach is to step $n$ down, assess the maximum $m$ for each one, and pick the best.  For a given $n$ you have $$m(m+1)+n^2 \le 1986\\ m(m+1) \le 1986-n^2\\ (m+\frac 12)^2 \le 1986\frac 14-n^2\\ m \le \sqrt{1986\frac 14-n^2}-\frac 12\\m=\left\lfloor \sqrt{1986\frac 14-n^2}-\frac 12\right\rfloor$$
A spreadsheet and copy down are your friend.

Comment: We also have to make sure that such a sum exists of even and odd integers.

Comment: You can always increase the $x$s or $y$s to get the sum right as long as $n$ is even-why do you need that?

Comment: The question says the $x_i$'s must even and the $y_j$'s must be odd.

Comment: True, but if I find a set of $x$s and $y$s that add to say $1968$ I can just increase the $x$s a bit, $2$ at a time, until I get to $1986$

Comment: I think this argument needs to be made more rigorous.

Comment: Also I think you made an algebraic mistake. How do you go from $\dfrac{1}{4}m(m+2) \leq 1986-n^2$ to $(m+1)^2 \leq 1987-n^2$?

Comment: I have fixed it, starting with the sum of the $x$'s being wrong.

Comment: Why must $n$ be even?

Comment: @Puzzled417 If $n$ is odd, $\sum y_i$ is also odd.

Comment: @RossMillikan How do you know there always exists such a set if $m$ equals that?

Comment: If the sum of the $x$'s is too small with them all as small as possible, which is what $m(m+1)$ represents, you can increase the top one as much as is needed to make the sum work.  There is no upper limit on $x_m$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, rewrite $m(m+1)+n^2\leq 1986$ as $(2m+1)^2+(2n)^2\leq 4\cdot 1986+1=7945$.  By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality,
$$\begin{align}
(2m+7n)+1=(2m+1)+\frac{7}{2}(2n)
&\leq \sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^2}\,\sqrt{(2m+1)^2+(2n)^2}
\\
&\leq\sqrt{\frac{53}{4}}\,\sqrt{7945}<325\,.
\end{align}$$
Thus, $$2m+7n<324\,.$$  The equality condition for equality case of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is $\frac{2m+1}{1}=\frac{2n}{7/2}$ and $(2m+1)^2+(2n)^2=7945$, which gives
$$(m,n)=\frac{1}{106}\left(-53\pm 2\sqrt{421085},\pm7\sqrt{421085}\right)\,.$$
The closest positive-integer pair $(m,n)$ that obeys $(2m+1)^2+(2n)^2\leq 7945$ is $$(m,n)=(11,43)\,,$$ for which $2m+7n=323$.

Comment: Recall that $n$ must be even.

Comment: Sure, I missed that part.  However, the requirement that $n$ is even makes $2m+7n\leq 322$.  It is very easy to modify the solution to handle that.  This bound achievable by the pair $(m,n)=(14,42)$, with $x_k=2k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,m$, $y_k=2k-1$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$, and $y_n=2n+11$.  There is no need for computer search, just wriggling around the Cauchy-Schwarz equality case.